# Data not available in K6 Default Function when passed from Setup()

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, k6

I am trying to write integration tests for a nodejs API. Here is the block of code that is causing me headaches:

```
    export default function (token) {
        console.log('Token value in Default(): ', token);
        group('All the API Smoke tests: \n', () => {
            failAuthorization();   
            getUserById(cognitoToken);
            createProject(cognitoToken);
        });  
    }

    export function setup() {
        const cognitoTokenPromise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            await getCognitoToken().then(token => {
                console.log("Token value in Setup():  ", token)
                resolve(token);
            }).catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });

        return cognitoTokenPromise;
    }
```

The getCognitoToken runs a POST request, async and returns a string. The log inside of setup() displays the correct value, but in the default function is shows as undefined. The order of the logs is correct in each iteration, which leads me to believe it is not a sync issue.

I have tried plenty of approaches:

- using a global variable, assign it in the setup(), still undefined in the default
- async/await
  and a bunch of other twitches here and there

Comment: You can only return static JSON data from the setup method, you cannot pass objects/functions with behavior. A promise is such an object.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used was this:
let cognitoToken;

```
export default async function () {
    if(!cognitoToken) {
        cognitoToken = await getCognitoToken();
    }
    ......
}
```